# Как узнать с какого сайта пришли на сайт с которого был сделан запрос

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Есть web api и есть сайт который отправляет запросы к этому api.
Собственно вопрос. Можно ли как-нибудь на стороне api узнать откуда пользователь пришел на сайт, который отправил запрос?

Comment: Нет. Если клиент сам о себе ничего не говорит, то можно узнать разве что ip.

Comment: Сайт, который делает запрос на WebApi, ваш? Что подразумевается под "откуда пользователь пришел на сайт"? Страна? IP? Сторонний сайт?

Comment: Сайт, который делает запрос на WebApi - мой. Откуда пришел - url

Comment: Ваш сайт отправляет запросы к WebApi из фронтенда или бэкенда? Бэкенд вашего сайта на каком языке/фреймворке написан?

Comment: из фронтенда. на чем бэкэнд никому не известно. На самом деле это просто кусок кода для вставки на любой сайт. я пока решил брать document.referrer и отправлять сервису. но хотелось бы все-таки сделать внутри сервиса

Comment: Традиционное решение описанной в вопросе между строк проблемы: API-ключи у клиентов.

Comment: если вам нужно получать адрес сайта, с которого пришли на страницу, с которой вам отправили запрос и если у вас есть доступ к коду, который отправляет запрос - `document.referrer` единственное решение. можете кодировать его на клиенте, чтобы не палиться. пожалуйста, добавьте все эти уточняющие данные в вопрос и постарайтесь максимально точно его сформулировать. Тогда можно будет составить грамотный ответ. Если не для вас (вероятно, вы уже решили проблему), то для тех, кто будет искать ответ в будущем.